# Can't use aggregate functions in drupal 7 views module

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-views

I'm trying to calculate the sum of a list of prices (decimal field) with the views module. And it just doesn't want to work... What am I doing wrong or.. is it just a bug ?

### Software used

- drupal v7.7
- cTools v7.x-1.0-rc1

### View configuration 1

- Use aggregation: Yes
- Fields : Title, sumPricesField
- Aggregation settings of sumPricesField : Aggregation type = SUM
- Group column = Value

### Result 1

sumPricesField remains blank in output, the only aggregation type that gives a value is COUNT

### View configuration 2

- Use aggregation: Yes
- Fields : Title, sumPricesField
- Aggregation settings of sumPricesField : Aggregation type = SUM
- Group column = Value
- Group columns (additional) = Entity ID result in MySQL error

### Result 2

**SQL error:**

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in 
your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near 'id) AS field_data_field_algembeo_entityid FROM
drupal_node node LEFT JOIN drupa' at line 1
```

**Generated Query**:

```
SELECT 
  node.title AS node_title, 
  node.nid AS nid, 
  node.created AS node_created, 
  MIN(node.nid) AS nid_1, 
  'node' AS field_data_field_bedrag_node_entity_type,
  SUM(field_data_field_bedrag.field_bedrag_value) AS field_data_field_bedrag_field_bedrag_value, 
  SUM(field_data_field_bedrag.entity id) AS field_data_field_bedrag_entityid
FROM 
  {node} node
  LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_bedrag} field_data_field_bedrag ON node.nid = field_data_field_bedrag.entity_id AND (field_data_field_bedrag.entity_type = node AND field_data_field_bedrag.deleted = 0)
WHERE 
  (( (node.status = '1') ))
GROUP BY 
  node_title, nid, node_created
ORDER BY 
  node_created DESC
LIMIT 
  10 OFFSET 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with SUMming up some float fields. I found this patch which solved the issue for me http://drupal.org/node/1194900
The mentioned jQuery error occurs on my site too after the patch but at least the aggregation works.